# Get contents of a tag with a particular class from a remote url in a different domain

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am trying to get the current english premier league table from http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb.html but i dont want the whole website, i just want the league table only, if you look keenly at the page source the `<table>` tag which has the league table doesnt have an id but has the class `.leagueTable` so i want just to get that table only.
This is my code

```
<head>
       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="jquery.xdomianajax.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='currentstandings'></div>  

      <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
loadEPLstandings(); 
});
    function loadEPLstandings () {
     $.ajax({
       url: 'http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb.html',
       type: 'GET',
       success: function(res) {        
          var success =  $(res).filter(".leagueTable"); 
          $('#currentstandings').html(success);
       }
     });
   }
</script>
```

but nothing gets loaded on that div! Where am i going wrong?
I used the cross domain ajax jQuery [plugin](https://github.com/padolsey/jquery.fn/blob/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js)

### **UPDATE:**

**The current answer works perfectly as a webpage on the browser**, but now i want this to be a chrome app instead of opening the browser and type the url,i added a manifest file with the relevant permissions but i hit a dead-end when i loaded my chrome app on to google chrome.
After several headaches and research i noticed that google chrome apps dont support ajax( or a flavour of it) calls i had to change my function to this but its not working

```
function loadEPLstandings () {
document.write("Sending request");
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      req.open("GET", "http://www.premierleague.com", true);
      req.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (req.readyState == 4) {
            if (req.status == 200) {
               var success =  $(res.responseText).find(".leagueTable")[0].innerHTML;
            $('#currentstandings').html(success);
                                       $("#currentstandings").contents().find("tr:has(p)").find("p").contents().unwrap();
            }
          }
        };
      req.send();
}
```

,where am i going wrong? Its not working as a webpage on the browser or as a chrome app?

Comment: it will be against the same origin policy constraints

Comment: @ArunPJohny whats your suggestion then? how would you come up with a solution to that problem?

Comment: @indago proxify request server side, search for it

Comment: you need to use your server as a proxy... sent an ajax request to your server... your server then sents a http request to the remote resource  and fetches the remote resource... then forwards it back the client

Comment: He's using a plugin that does allow cross-domain requests, by routing all your ajax calls through a proxy... https://github.com/padolsey/jquery.fn/blob/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only see a couple of things wrong with the code, which I've fixed here...

```
function loadEPLstandings () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb.html',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(res) {        
            var success =  $(res.responseText).find(".leagueTable")[0].innerHTML;
            $('#currentstandings').html(success);
        }
    });
}
```

Firstly, you were trying to filter `res`, but that's an object.  You need the property `responseText`.  Secondly, I've used `find()` instead of `filter()` as it was returning nothing.  Finally I added the `[0].innerHTML` to get the DOM element selected by jQuery and return the inner html value, so you can set it using `html()`.

Comment: Thanks alot, this has worked,perfectly! Thats just what i needed, it loads just the table standings only! 1+

Comment: i want to hook this up in my chrome as a chrome app but i have noticed google chrome doesnt support ajax i must change that code to CORS XMLHttpRequest, check out my updated question for the changes i have done, but its not working both as a webpage on a browser or as a chrome app, what could be wrong?

Comment: The cross domain ajax library you were previously using is what allowed you to make the cross domain call, by modifying `$.ajax`.  Since you're no longer using that then it can't work.  You need to include to 2 libraries that you included in the question originally and go back to the working code.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final code, had to prune out all the `<p>` tags

```
$(document).ready(function(){
loadEPLstandings(); 
});
    function loadEPLstandings () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb.html',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(res) {        
            var success =  $(res.responseText).find(".leagueTable")[0].innerHTML;
            $('#currentstandings').html(success);
            $("#currentstandings").contents().find("tr:has(p)").find("p").contents().unwrap();
        }
    });
}
```